# is this correct usage of verb "be"?

Tags: verb-usage

Can I use this line in a song, addressing the fires and the winds:

> You fires and winds, please, let the forests be

for them not to get angry anymore and let the forests exist and not destroy them anymore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The expression [let someone/something be](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_someone%2Fsomething_be) generally means **stop interfering**, though most people would accept its usage in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You have it right.  It means to leave the thing alone, as in the "to exist" sense of the verb "to be". Example: "Let it be." (song by the Beatles)